# NameError: global name not defined when calling method inside class

Tags: function, python-2.7, runtime-error

I'm trying to call a different function inside the same class from my main function and I can seem to figure where the error is.

I keep getting this error relating to functions not being defined and I'm not sure how to resolve it:

> NameError: global name 'results' is not defined

```
class Darts:
     def main() :
          print results()

     def results() :
          round_result_totals = "Stuff"
          return round_result_totals

    #RUNNING CODE
    main()
```

Comment: The code where you are actually calling the function would be very helpful.

Comment: *updated*  It's just simply calling main()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure that you define properly `self` in your functions and **initialize** an object first before you do anything else. You can't just call a `function` from a `class` without creating an `instance` of that `class` and calling a `function` from that `instance` (NOT THE CLASS). Usually you want to have an `__init__` in your python classes.

```
class Darts:
     def __init__(self):
         pass

     def main(self):
          print(self.results())

     def results(self):
          round_result_totals = "Stuff"
          return round_result_totals

Dart1 = Darts()
Dart1.main()
```

If you want to use variables, `self` is critical too for encapsulation.

```
class Darts:
     def __init__(self):
         self.a = 500

     def main(self):
          self.a += 1
          print(self.a)


Dart1 = Darts()
Dart1.main()
```

Comment: how would this work if you created some variables for the class in the init function and needed to reference them in the main function.  So say you had: a = 500 in the init class and needed to use 'a' in the main class to increment it.  "a += 1"

Comment: Thanks a bunch!  I've been trying to teach myself python and this was extremely helpful to read your responses and the links your provided!

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass self (the instance of your object) into your object's methods.

```
class Darts:
     def main(self) :
          print self.results()

     def results(self) :
          round_result_totals = "Stuff"
          return round_result_totals
```

Answer (score 1):

You're missing all of the required references to `self` inside your class.  It should look like this:

```
class Darts:
    def main(self) :
        print self.results()

    def results(self) :
        round_result_totals = "Stuff"
        return round_result_totals
```

Here is the [Python documentation on classes](https://docs.python.org/3.4/tutorial/classes.html#a-first-look-at-classes).  And the fifth paragraph of [this section](https://docs.python.org/3.4/tutorial/classes.html#a-first-look-at-classes) makes reference to the convention of `self`.

Briefly: the first argument to a method of a Python class is automatically passed in a reference to the instance of that class from which the method is being called (provided it is being called as an instance method).  This is done automatically by Python's interpreter.  This parameter still needs to be explicitly stated in the method definition, however, and the convention is to call it `self`.